# How can I resume an Activity without reloading and processing its data all over again?

Tags: java, android

I have some list activities, one leading to the other. Whenever I press return and return to the previous list activity and then back again to this activity again, it does the whole onCreate processing all over again.

How can I make it remember the data that was loaded on to the list?

```
public class Modules extends ListActivity {
    PortalHandler portalHandler;
    Login login;
    ArrayList<String> menuItems;
    Document portal;
    String portalHtml;
    Elements modules;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        menuItems = new ArrayList<String>();
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras().getBundle("extras");
        portalHtml = extras.getString("portalHtml");
        portal = Jsoup.parse(portalHtml);
        modules = portal.select(".courselink ");
        for (int i = 0; i < modules.size(); i++) {
            menuItems.add(modules.get(i).text()
                    .substring(0, modules.get(i).text().indexOf("(")));
        }
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.modules,
                menuItems));
        ListView listView = getListView();
        listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

            }
        });

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding  `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"` in your Manifest file

Secondly, do nothing in onStart() and onResume().
Call your Activity like this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Second.this,First.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can save data either in Shared preferences, or use the the saved instance state via [onSaveInstanceState()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29), which you can then access the data on the savedInstanceState Bundle that is the parameter to your onCreate() method.